# Missing :ASP.NET Web Application Template (VS2012)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to create a VS 2012 project from the "ASP.NET Web Application" template. It is not in the list. "ASP.NET Empty Web Application" and "ASP.NET Web Forms Application" appears but not the one I'm looking for.

I am intersted to create a Web API project. Kindly help

Comment: Did come across this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0fyc0azh(v=vs.110).aspx    It says to run devenv.exe with the /installvstemplates switch

Answer (score 0):

***ASP.NET Web Application*** is in **VS2013**.

In ***VS2012***, select ***ASP.Net MVC 4 Web Application***. Then select ***Web API***.

[image]

[image]

Comment: His problem is that ASP.NET Web Application is missing from the default template list

Comment: @KidBilly ***ASP.NET Web Application*** is in VS2013; it is not available in VS2012.

Comment: It's also available in 2010, just so ya know.

Comment: @KidBilly I do not see ***ASP.NET Web Application*** option in VS2012's New Project dialog. If you see that, please post the screen shot.

Comment: I'm not arguing that it's available in VS2012 (admittedly, I didn't realize it until you posted it).  My last comment was just stating that it's available in VS2013 AND VS2010

Comment: ***ASP.NET Web Application*** is introduced since ***VS2005***, but it is not the point. OP is asking how to create ***Web API*** in ***VS2012***, because he could not find what is available in ***VS2013***. No hard feelings; end of the day, we are just trying to help each other. ;)